# Show mini menu on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have some "media" divs like this...

[image]

When I hover a div, I would like to animate a little toolbar, so it looks like this...

[image]

Is there a JQuery control "out there" that already does this or anybody can point me in a direction on how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/ and set `hover: true` in the options

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a javascript for this, it's a perfect use for CSS. You can make a child element appear on parent's hover

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yyans8c2/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    Item #1

    <div class="toolbar">toolbar</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    Item #2

    <div class="toolbar">toolbar</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.toolbar {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;

    background-color: #DDD;
}

div.item:hover .toolbar {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) ... I will try to build on this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hover()` and `.animate()` functions:

**NOTE:** Perhaps you would like the tooltip to remain visible after hover. In that case comment the line:

```
 //$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.tooltip').stop().animate({'right': '-100px'}, 300, 'easeOutExpo');
```

```js
$('.img-wrapper').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.tooltip').stop().animate({'right': '0'}, 300, 'easeOutExpo');
}, function() {
  //$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.tooltip').stop().animate({'right': '-100px'}, 300, 'easeOutExpo');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
}

.text-wrapper {
  width: 420px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  float: left;
}

.tooltip {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  background-color: #777;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img-wrapper">img</div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
     <span>text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">tooltip</div>
</div>
```